# Confusion in #import vs @class

Tags: ios, object

Here is situation :

I have `ViewController` that have SideMenu that need to import

```
#import "SideMenu.h"
```

A I've to call the delegate method of `ViewController` from sidemenu so I've to import `ViewController` in sidemenu that lead me to error :

```
Cannot find protocol declaration for 'onClickCategory'
```

So I've to import both files to each other.
How to handle this situation?

`@class` not work in both class.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/class-vs-import

Answer (score 0):

As Ben Gottlieb answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253051/whats-the-difference-between-import-and-class-and-when-should-i-use-one-over)

> ## import brings the entire header file in question into the current file; any files that THAT file #imports are also included. @class, on
>
> the other hand (when used on a line by itself with some class names),
> just tells the compiler "Hey, you're going to see a new token soon;
> it's a class, so treat it that way).

Comment: it give me error on

   ' objSideMenu = [[SideMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"SideMenu" bundle:nil];'

 Receiver 'SideMenu' for class message is a forward declaration